# Why :target=>"_blank" is not working in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, erb

From the google support page https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en#GA

I have added the below code.

```
<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Google Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

Now I want to modify my onclick attribute of an image link to be tracked so I have used the below code

```
<%= link_to image_tag("banner.png", :alt => "ad"), 
          "https://www.someexternalsite.com", 
          :target=>"_blank" ,
          :onclick=> "trackOutboundLink('https://www.seomexternalsite.com'); return false;"
%>
```

I have not checked if the tracking is working yet, but :target=>"_blank" does not seem to be working, the link is opening on the same page. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: with `return false;` you are telling the anchor to not follow the link

Comment: Thanks, but now that I have removed return false; it is opening the links twice, once on a new tab and another on the same page..can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `return false` does not allow the anchor to follow the link, so the first fix is to remove that code from the `onclick`
2. In your `trackOutboundLink` your are telling in the callback to change the current document location to the new url (the anchor url) so also remove the callback:

   var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url);
   }